# Nested Variables in Substring selection

Tags: batch-file

I'm struggling to get this "Substring"-Selection done dynamically:

```
set input=%input:~4%
```

I would like to have something like

```
set input=%%input:~%length% %%
```

But all my attempts with double %% and ! and many more have failed. Hope you can tell me, how nested variables like this work in windows batch files.

Many thanks in advance,

best regards,

marcus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many possible ways

This uses the fact that `CALL` starts the batch parser a second time

```
set length=4
call set input=%%input:~%length%%%
```

With delayed expansion it's the most stable and secure solution

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set length=4
set input=!input:~%length%!
```

Sometimes it's even useful to use a FOR parameter

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set length=4
for /F %%n in ("!length!") do (        
    set input=!input:~%%~n!
)
```